# How to register a URL with 3 part naming?

Tags: url, domain-registration, tld

My objective is to have a URL like -  **m.af.ia.**

So, assuming I register a TLD web-site called **m.af** with Afghanistan (af) ... is there any  way I can set up my server infrastructure so that the URL I handout would be - **m.af.ia.**

And not m.af/ia.

Is there a possibility of achieving this?

Answer (score 7):

DNS is a hierarchy, with the topmost element at the far right.

If you want a DNS entry for `m.af.ia` you would need to register `af.ia`.
This is currently impossible: The `.ia` top-level domain does not exist according to [the root zone database](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/db/#).

You can petition ICANN for a new top-level domain, but I doubt you'll get it (and it would be **hideously** expensive...)

Answer (score 3):

In that case, you'd need to own the `af` domain under an `ia` top-level domain (which I'm sure ICANN will provide for a scant investment of hundreds-of-thousands per year), and make a subdomain of `m`.

Under a domain that you control (`af`), you can create any number or structure of subdomains that you please.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only way this would work is if you could find a provider that allows you to register ".ia" addresses. Your current/example name is in the ".af" DNS namespace, so any domains you create will always end in .af